# Does Grunt offer some "externals" option similar to what webpack provides?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gruntjs, config, externals

We know that using webpack sometimes we do not want to include a package code inline in our output file(s) as it is assumed that it will be available on the Browser globally at runtime. 
This is done because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.

This is explained a bit [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html)

My question is, can we do something similar in Grunt?

Actually I am working on an application which uses Grunt and I want it to ignore any `require("react")` lines as it is already being added to page via `script` tag.